# Angularjs to restfull webservices conection

Tags: angularjs

i have created one restfull webservice (ex:http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall) i am trying to connect that restfull web service using angularjs but i am getting failure

my sample code is

```
$http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall').success(function(response){
  $window.alert('success')
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $window.alert('failure')
});
```

i want solution for this immediately please mail me if any one have the answer or sample code.

Comment: can you get a more specific error than just 'failure'?

Comment: You should post what errors you are getting in the console, if any.

Comment: What you are getting in console log? Is your server side method is get. can you show your server method?

Comment: In console i am not getting any error but i want to success and get the data from restfull weservices i have data like

Comment: i have data in restfull webservises like {"product":[{"id":"p01","name":"Name 1","price":"3000.0"},{"id":"p02","name":"Name 2","price":"4000.0"},{"id":"p03","name":"Name 3","price":"5000.0"},{"id":"p04","name":"Name 4","price":"6000.0"}]}

Comment: i want to get this data so i have used $http.get('http://localhost:8080/RestfulAndAngularJS_Server/rest/product/findall').success(function(response){
  $window.alert('success')
}).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  $window.alert('failure')
});

Comment: but i am getting failure instead of  success please help me this is urgent

Comment: if any code please  mail to pandukp132@gmail.com

Comment: possible duplicate of [angularjs with restfull webservice communication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31579682/angularjs-with-restfull-webservice-communication)

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your REST is working as u want with Google postman

Answer (score 0):

when in your restfull web services you are returning a Json format data so add the following highlighted thing in your webservice,

return Response.status(200).entity(empList).**header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")**.build();

Comment: Please don't, use the Access control as intended, and only whitelist the domains you need.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [docs about angular's $resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).